# Datatable number conversion into octal

Tags: javascript, datatables

In data table I am facing one challenge

I have some number which has leading zero (0461). Data is displaying properly in data table but when I click on that number and passing in one method then its converting to other number probably octal number

For example 0461 converted into 86.

Please suggest something

My data table code is

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
            processing : true,
            serverSide : true,
            pageLength : 10,
            ajax : {
                url : "/codes",
                data : function(data) {
                }
            },
            columns : [ {
                "data" : "code",
                "name" : "Code",
                "title" : "Code",
                "render" : function(data) {
                    // From here I am passing 0461
                    return '<a class="link" onclick="return searchCode('+data+');">' + data + '</a>';
                }
            } ],
            columnDefs : [ {
                "targets" : [ 1],
                "searchable" : false
            }, {
                "targets" : [ 0],
                "orderable" : true
            } ]
        });


// But here getting 86      
function searchCode(code) {
        console.log(code);
    }
```

In data table data look like below

[image]

Comment: try adding double quotes around the data parameter you are passing in `return searchCode("'+data+'");`

Comment: Tried above one but getting Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input

Comment: Octal '0461' would be 305 decimal

Comment: Correct.. Any solution

Answer (score 0):

Found below solution

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
            processing : true,
            serverSide : true,
            pageLength : 10,
            ajax : {
                url : "/codes",
                data : function(data) {
                }
            },
            columns : [ {
                "data" : "code",
                "name" : "Code",
                "title" : "Code",
                "render" : function(data) {
                    // From here passing this instead of data
                    return '<a class="link" onclick="return searchCode(this);">' + data + '</a>';
                }
            } ],
            columnDefs : [ {
                "targets" : [ 1],
                "searchable" : false
            }, {
                "targets" : [ 0],
                "orderable" : true
            } ]
        });


// It will print what we will pass from above method    
function searchCode(code) {
        console.log(code.text); // print 0461
    }
```